# Problems running a mySQL query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code below is not returning any value into my `$result` variable. The database connection is good. But it doesn't appear to be returning any values for the `$result` variable.

I do have data in the `player` table and there is a `player_id` value of 1 and 2 in said table.

The print out of the echos when run is this. when passing the integers 1 and 2 into the function.

Database connected

```
SELECT * 
FROM player 
WHERE player_id = 1
```

Results not an array.

Database connected

```
SELECT * 
FROM player 
WHERE player_id = 2
```

Results not an array.

```
function displayName($player_id)
{
    // setting database variables
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbName;host=localhost';
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    // try to make connection
    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Database connected <br>";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    //  create, print, and execute the query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM player WHERE player_id = $player_id";
    echo "$sql <br>";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //if the query returned an array
    if (is_array($result))
    {
        // if the array has data
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            Echo "Result is an array and has values. <br>";
            Echo "$result[0] $result[1]. <br>";
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No results. <br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Results not an array. <br>";
    }
    //close the database connection.
    $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($result);` - what does that produce?

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(40) "SELECT * FROM player WHERE player_id = 1" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO query returns an object, not an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

It will return false on failure so just check

```
if ($result) {
   ...
```

Comment: Well I'll be.  I am just learning PDO.  I didn't know that.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks.  $result is an object.